# Asserting SMTP connector attributes in a flow

Tags: java, unit-testing, mule

i have a subflow which ends in an SMTP endpoint.
I have mocked the smtp:outbound-endpoint using MUnit to verify that the attributes are being specified as expected given the flow input.

But the one thing I can't verify is the content type/mime type. This attribute is set on the associated connector. But it is not possible to mock the connector as message processor it seems.

How can validate whether the mimeType on the smtp:connector is being set to a certain value?

For example (below), if my xml has an invalid name configuring the contentType below, how could I write a test to prevent it:

```
<smtp:connector name="smtpConnector"  doc:name="SMTP" contentType="#[flowVars.someInvalidName]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String contentTypeInbound = message.getProperty("content-type", PropertyScope.INBOUND);
MimeType mt = new MimeType(contentTypeInbound);
String mimeType = mt.getPrimaryType() + "/" + mt.getSubType();
assertEquals(expectedMimeType, mimeType);
```

Hope it helps.